# azdata erroring out due to config file error

Tags: config, kubectl, azure-aks, sql-server-2019

All,

The admin setup a 3 node AKS cluster today. I got the kube/config file update by running the az command
az aks get-credentials --name AKSBDCClus --resource-group AAAA-Dev-RG --subscription AAAA-Subscription.

I was able to run all the kubectl commands fine but when I tried setting up the SQLServer 2019 BDC by running azdata bdc create it gave me an error `Failed to complete kube config setup.`

Since it was something to do with azdata and kubectl I checked the azdata logs and this is what I see in the azdata.log.

```
Loading default kube config from C:\Users\rgn\.kube\config
Invalid kube-config file. Expected all values in kube-config/contexts list to have 'name' key
```

Thinking the config file could have got corrupted I tried running `az aks get-credentials --name AKSBDCClus --resource-group AAAA-Dev-RG --subscription AAAA-Subscription.`

This time I got whole lot of error

```
The client 'rgn@mycompany.com' with object id 'XXXXX-28c3-YYYY-ZZZZ-AQAQAQd' 
does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action' 
over scope '/subscriptions/Subscription-ID/resourceGroups/
ResourceGroup-Dev-RG/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/AKSCluster' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

I logged out and logged back into azure and retried but got the same errors as above. I was able to even stop the VM Scale before I logged for the day. Everything works fine but I'm unable to run azdata script.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
rgn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the **config file was bad**. I deleted the file and ran "az aks get-credentials" (after the necessary permissions to run it) and it worked. The size of old config is 19kb but the new one is 10k.

I guess, I might have messed it up while testing "az aks get-credentials"